# PHP Mysql ranking

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Mysql database looking like this:

http://i.imgur.com/bLlXrGg.png

and I am calculating rank using this formula:

```
SELECT Name, Kills, Wins, Losses, Killstreak, 
(((Wins * 5) + (Kills / 10) / (Losses / 10)) + ((Wins + Losses) / 50)) +
Killstreak as rank
FROM `hgstats` WHERE `Name` = '$inputPlayer'"
```

and that outputs the sum but I would like to have it say 1,2,3 and so on, how would I do this from within the query.

Comment: No pics please. Just nice, clean DDLs!!

Comment: Are you looking for `ORDER BY rank` ?

Comment: @Justinas no because the number outputted by the top row would be 642, what i want is 1,2,3 and so on so its a rank number

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you would use variables.  Assuming you want the rank for a given player, you can assign all the ranks and then choose the row(s) you want:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM (SELECT Name, Kills, Wins, Losses, Killstreak, 
             (((Wins * 5) + (Kills / 10) / (Losses / 10)) + ((Wins + Losses) / 50)) + Killstreak as rankvalue,
             @rn := @rn + 1 as rank
      FROM `hgstats` CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @rn := 0) vars
      ORDER BY rankvalue
     ) r
WHERE `Name` = '$inputPlayer'"
```